# Validating Folder Selection

Tags: excel, vba

In the portion of the code below I have a Function called FolderPick which returns the file path of a selected folder via a dialogue box.  I then strip the folder path down to find the name of the selected selected folder.  That all works as intended.

What I would like to do is verify that the name of the selected folder is one of the approved names.  I was initially thinking of using a series of IF statements, then I thought about using the case statement.  So I am pretty sure the syntax for my CASEs are wrong and that you can only have one value per case.

Is my only choice here an IF statement with a lot of ORs?

Also is there a format for a catch all CASE?  i.e. none of the previous cases were a match so do this?

```
Pickafolder:

FolderPath = FolderPick

Foldername = Left(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 1)
Foldername = RIght(Foldername, Len(Foldername) - InStrRev(Foldername, "\"))

Select Case Foldername
    Case Foldername = "OPSS" Or Foldername = "SSP" Or Foldername = "OPSD" Or Foldername = "MTOD" Or Foldername = "SSD"

        'do something

    Case Foldername = "West" Or Foldername = "Eastern" Or Foldername = "Northeastern" Or Foldername = "Northwestern" Or Foldername = "Head Office"

        'inser "NSP\ before foldername

    Case Foldername = "NSP"

        'msgbox "Pick the  NSP sub folder"
        GoTo Pickafolder

    Case Foldername <> any other case

        'msgbox "Inappropriate directory to upload from. Please select one of the CPS download directories"
        GoTo Pickafolder

 End Select
```

Comment: Why does the I in RIght get capitalized by my VBA Editor?

Comment: because you probably once accidentally defined somewhere something like `Dim RIght` and VBA somehow remembers. Search for it and if you do not find it, just write anywhere at to top of your module `Dim Right` then it gets changed. You can remove that statement after it changed to a lower case `i`.

Comment: Please don't roll back valid edits. If a tag is marked "Pending removal" then don't use it. You're just creating work for others when the tag is removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, you can use "," instead of OR

```
Select Case FolderName
    Case "OPSS", "SSP", "Something", "MTOD", "SSD"

        'do something


    Case "West", "Eastern", "Northeastern", "Northwestern", "Head Office"

        'inser "NSP\ before foldername

    Case "NSP"

        'msgbox "Pick the  NSP sub folder"
        'GoTo Pickafolder

    Case Else

        'msgbox "Inappropriate directory to upload from. Please select one of the CPS download directories"
        'GoTo Pickafolder

 End Select
```

Comment: I did not realize there was a CASE ELSE.  That is awesome!  I will try this momentarily